# The response could not be parsed

Tags: java, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am using redstone-xmlrpc-1.1.1 api with my code and getting this error:

```
redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: The response could not be parsed.

    at redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.handleResponse(Unknown Source)
    at redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.endCall(Unknown Source)
    at redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.bican.wordpress.$Proxy1.newMediaObject(Unknown Source)
    at net.bican.wordpress.Wordpress.newMediaObject(Wordpress.java:582)
    at WordpressPost.DataWordpressPost.DataPost(DataWordpressPost.java:53)
    at arrestcentral.ArrestData.readPdf(ArrestData.java:420)
    at arrestcentral.ArrestData.main(ArrestData.java:447)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.arrestcentral.com/XMLrpc.php?
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1478)
    ... 9 more
```

can anyone help me why I am unable to post on wordpress..

Answer (score 1):

Well, the exception tells you what's happened - you've tried to fetch a URL of

```
http://www.arrestcentral.com/XMLrpc.php?
```

... and it was giving you an HTTP 404 (not found) error. You probably need to change the URL, but you should have more idea of what that URL should be than we do.

Answer (score 0):

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.arrestcentral.com/XMLrpc.php?` should have given you a clue:

Nothing was found at the URL you specified. This means that the server returned a HTTP response with [the error code 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404).

You *either* mistyped the URL or it no longer exists (at this location).